# How do I directly change Style Properties in JS using document.getElementsByClassName("Class_Name")

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change CSS property background color using class name in JavaScript. My code is as below

```
function changeColor(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("flex-items").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

The function changeColor() is called with a onclick event of a button.

```
<button onclick="changeColor()">Change Color</button>
```

Is there a solution to this problem?

[Note there are many div boxes with class name "flex-items" and I want to change all their background color on a single click.]

Comment: You're supposed to do some research before asking here. The short answer is that `.getElementsByClassName()` returns more than one `HTMLElement` so your code has address that. Or just use jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just push them to an array and loop it through.

```
window.changeBG = function() { 
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
    for(var i in items) items[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red'; 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gugalondon/69syLdg1/